# Can't login with Facebook SDK on cordova iOS after changing permissions

Tags: ios, cordova, facebook-ios-sdk, cordova-plugins

I'm using Cordova latest version with this plugin https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4... In the first version,  I was getting permission for only:

```
id,email,birthday
```

And in the 2nd version, I am getting permission for:

```
id,email,birthday,gender,first_name,last_name
```

which causes the following error:

```
domain=com.facebook.sdk.login code=304
```

But if I removed the app and re-installed it, it works fine!

So, what should I do now? the app in production, and all users can't login, and it is really hard to ask all users to remove the app and re-install it! any idea to release another version with a patch to fix this issue?

I think there is a solution here: [ios facebook sdk 4.0 login error code 304](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29408299/ios-facebook-sdk-4-0-login-error-code-304), but I'm not a good Objective C developer to know how to implement it in the plugin!

Answer (score 0):

I followed this link: [ios facebook sdk 4.0 login error code 304](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29408299/ios-facebook-sdk-4-0-login-error-code-304)

And made this patch:
https://github.com/mabdelfattah/cordova-plugin-facebook4/commit/e55b974ee62a6c98293fadda688e0382b5e2d45c#diff-c05c80840d093f0d14fb66a56466e521

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the cordova facebook plugin call `facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus()` caches the FB response. It doesn't allow us to force a server trip in that call (whereas in the FB Javascript SDK it does).

I resolve the issue by calling `facebookConnectPlugin.login()` when I get 304. That forces a server trip to reload the FB permission upon a fresh login.