# Issue with Facebook login working with only developer account

Tags: facebook, flutter

if i'm trying to login with another account then i didn't get user information.

```
void initiateFacebookLogin() async {
    var facebookLoginResult = await facebookLogin
        .logInWithReadPermissions(['email', 'public_profile']);

    switch (facebookLoginResult.status) {
      case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
        _fblogin.sink.add(FacebookLoginData(false, ""));
        break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
        _fblogin.sink.add(FacebookLoginData(false, ""));
        break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
        var graphResponse = await http.get(
            'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email&access_token=${facebookLoginResult.accessToken.token}');

        var profile = json.decode(graphResponse.body);
        _fblogin.sink.add(FacebookLoginData(true, profile));
        break;
    }
  }
```

in iOS device error message :

> iOS - Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.login Code=304 "(null)"
>   in android device error message 
>   user login with different account.

Comment: Is your app set to Live mode yet, or is it still in dev mode? And if the latter, is the user account added to one of the roles in the app dashboard?

Comment: app is in already live mode, no user account doesn't add in any role in the app dashboard.

Comment: I implemented using  flutter_facebook_login: ^2.0.0 library and it works fine. Hope it will also be helpful for you

Comment: @RohitSingh i'm also try that but not issue of version miss match.

Comment: @ParthBhanderi please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29408299/ios-facebook-sdk-4-0-login-error-code-304).

Answer (score 1):

The **first thing that needs to be done inside that method** in order to make it work 100% of the time (it would fail when the user changes accounts or the access token gets refreshed):

```
await FacebookAuth.instance.logOut();
```